# my button keep displaying the same frame in adobe flash action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame

I have been doing this for a week and i cannot get it right. Im still new with adobe flash and currently doing assignment on BMI calculator.
but my button keep directing me to the 'obese' frame eventho the result should be underweight. there's no error reported by the compiler.

this is my coding.

```
stop();

*btn_calculate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, countbmi);*  
*function countbmi(e:MouseEvent):void*  
{
    var num1=Number(weight.text);
    var num2=Number(heightm.text);
    var num3:Number= num1/(num2*num2);

if (num3<=18.5)
{
    gotoAndPlay(7); 
}

if (num3>18.5 && num3<=24.9)
{
    gotoAndPlay(8);
}

if (num3>25 && num3<29.9)
{
    gotoAndPlay(9);
}

else
{
    gotoAndPlay(10);
}
}
```

Comment: can you avoid pasting code as images as its making search/copy/paste imposible ?

Comment: already change it. :)

Comment: Let's start with the obvious: you need to have a 'stop()' command at each of  your frames so that the MovieClip that contains them doesn't simply run through all of the frames. Do you have that?

Comment: Next, don't you want to say 'gotoAndStop' at each frame?

Comment: And finally, instead of your 'else' statement just say 'if (num3>29.8){ gotoAndPlay(10);}'